# How to get checked exception from cxf's WebClient or how to handle Exceptions

Tags: java, web-services, exception, cxf, cxf-client

I created a little client api to connect to a proprietary rest-like service. I use `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient` for connection. On this client i call `get()` and `post()`.

The problem is that if service is unavailable or to slow (i set timeout to 10s) i only get RuntimeException of type `javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException`. But i need a checked exception for all kinds of connection issues to let users of api react on them. How to do this?

Here is the code that configures the WebClient client:

```
private void configureClient() {
    ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) config.getConduit();
    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT);
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
}
```

Comment: Catch the runtimeexception in a try { }catch(...){ handle the message and throw your own checkedexception.

Comment: is there a way (provided by cxf) to do this globally and not on every call? I only want to be sure before i begin to write this boiler plate code. If this is the only way i probably extend webclient and throw checked exception there?!

Comment: if you want it globally, may be using AOP could be a solution to study.

Comment: Please say how. There seems aop in place alread. console says: "org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
Warnung: Interceptor for {http://192.168.190.128:50000}WebClient has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message." Can i leverage this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException,  java.net.ConnectException` to catch connection related exception(Though I don't remember the exact exception class) and `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientException` to capture other JAXRS exception such has 400 415 etc.

Comment: If it is throwing a javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException which is a direct subtype of RuntimeException, not of any of those exceptions you mention, how does that help?